# Past tense or present perfect? "I told Link about you before I even knew" or “ I have told Link about you before I even knew”?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

> I wish I could blame this on him, but I **told** Link about you before I even **knew**.---- from the TV show Grey's Anatomy

Present perfect "have told," IMO, should be used rather than the past tense "told" in the original context, as there is a clear sequence of events.

So which one is best fitting here? Or both are interchangeable here?

Comment: No. This is describing a single event in the past, so the past tense is correct.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Single event? I think there are two events: I told and I even knew

Comment: But "I knew" isn't an event.

Comment: @DanielRoseman so what's the definition of an event? If those two separate things don't count as two events

Comment: @mirthspritzsultryobscurantism There isn't a rule that says "You have to use the present perfect if there were two events."  It's perfectly fine, and actually more normal, to say something like "I **ate** fish and then I **ate** cheese" even though there are two events.